# Clean text for each sentence in Python in a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, text-processing

I am trying to do some text cleaning in Python for sentiment analysis. But instead of lumping all the text together and separating them, I want to clean the text by each sentence. To do that I used a `for` loop in my function but the issue is that it only returns 1 of the sentences in my dataframe.

```
[In] data = pd.read_csv('twitter_AC.csv')

[In] data.head()

0    We're #hiring! Click to apply: Vaccine Special...
1    Can you recommend anyone for this #job? Vaccin...
2    We're #hiring! Read about our latest #job open...
3    We're #hiring! Read about our latest #job open...
4    We're #hiring! Read about our latest #job open...

Name: text, dtype: object


[In] def text_process(text):

    '''
    Takes in a string of text, then performs the following:
    1. Remove all punctuation
    2. Remove all stopwords
    3. Return the cleaned text as a list of sentences
    '''
    for i in text:
        nopunc = [word for word in i if word not in string.punctuation]
        nopunc = ''.join(nopunc)
    return [nopunc.lower()]

[In] text_process(data)

[Out] ['were hiring read about our latest job opening here immunization rn  httpstcopxczq5zrhr healthcare fairfax va careerarc']
```

I can't figure out why the function is not outputting all the rows from my dataframe. Also, I don't see why its pulling out just a random row instead of the first row.

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating over every element in your collection, but each time you're overwritting `nopunc` variable.

So, you are just returning the last line traversed.

Try with this:

```
def text_process(text):                                                                                                                        

    '''
    Takes in a string of text, then performs the following:
    1. Remove all punctuation
    2. Remove all stopwords
    3. Return the cleaned text as a list of sentences
    '''
    nopuncList = []
    for i in text:
        nopunc = [word for word in i if word not in string.punctuation]
        nopunc = ''.join(nopunc)
        nopuncList.append(nopunc.lower())
    return nopuntList
```

Answer (score 0):

You loop is a bit malformed.  I would suggest using a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) like:

```
def text_process(text):  
    return [''.join(word for word in i if word not in string.punctuation).lower() 
            for i in text]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting `nopunc` variable again and again. So as a result, your function is returning the last row. Try having a empty list and append the results to it for every iteration.

```
def text_process(text):

    '''
    Takes in a string of text, then performs the following:
    1. Remove all punctuation
    2. Remove all stopwords
    3. Return the cleaned text as a list of sentences
    '''
    result = list()
    for i in text:
        nopunc = [word for word in i if word not in string.punctuation]
        nopunc = ''.join(nopunc)
        result.append(nopunc.lower())
    return result
```

Hope this helps.